# Strip BBCode from string

Tags: python, bbcode

I'm trying to find a way to strip BBCode from a string. The modules that I've found (BBCode and Post Markup) seem to only translate them to HTML rather than just remove the BBCode and return a clean string. If I'm missing something and one of those actually does what I'm asking I'd love some direction on it :)

Otherwise, are there any ways to strip BB Code from a string and return plain text?

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is actually within the [`bbcode`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bbcode) module. Unfortunately, the relevant method is not in the [documentation](http://bbcode.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), but if you search through the code it's there: `Parser.strip()`. For example:

```
import bbcode

parser = bbcode.Parser()
code = "[code]a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5][/code]"
plain_txt = parser.strip(code)
print(plain_txt)
```

```
'a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'
```

Unfortunately, both Robᵩ's regex-based [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31900979/1426065) and [`postmarkup`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/postmarkup) suffer from the same problem - the inability to differentiate between BBCode (`[list][*]Item 1[*]Item 2[/list]`, `[color=red]I hate color-blind people![/color]`, etc.) and the embedded code example I used above (they both return `a =`), or a line like

```
I'm feeling sad :[ But, eating ice cream cheers me up! :]
```

which simply returns

```
I'm feeling sad :
```

This is possible because `bbcode` tokenizes the string first, searching for valid BBCode tokens, and identifying the rest as just parts of the overall text. `Parser.strip()` then just throws the BBCode tokens away and reassembles the text, while the formatting methods turn those tokens into XHTML markup, and splice in the rest where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your needs, this might be sufficient:

```
#UNTESTED
import re
with open("some_input_file.txt") as input_file:
    for s in input_file:
        s = re.sub('\[.*?]','',s)
        print s
```

Comment: That'll strip out *all* square brackets and their content, though... bad if you have embedded code, or certain emoticons, or other things.

Comment: I think that's what OP asked for -- " just remove the BBCode and return a clean string".

Comment: Sorry, I could have been clearer. I meant embedded *computer* code. For example, `[code]a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5][/code]` is valid BBCode, specifying a `<code></code>` block, but processed with your answer will just yield `a = `.

Comment: Or, you could have a hypothetical line like: "*I'm feeling sad :[ But, eating ice cream cheers me up! :]*"

Comment: THanks - this is perfect for what I'm going for. It's for parsing work tickets from an API - so there shouldn't be any :[ or :] faces, or really []'s used at all for anything but bbcode :D You're awesome! If I had more rep I'd be able to upvote you here :(